# How do you pass in the get; method of a property to a method that accepts a Func?

Tags: c#

I have this:

`public void GetFish(Func<List<Fish>> goFishing) { ... }`

and this:

`public List<Fish> getFish { get { return ... } }`

If the second line was actually a method, I could just do

`GetFish(getFish);`

However because it's a property, the above will return an error.

What I need is something like:

`GetFish(getFish.Getter)`

Any ideas?

Comment: Why are you naming your properties "getX"? If you have a setter, do you have a seperate property, "setX", rather than having the getter and setter as the same property?

Comment: It's an override of an abstract method that provides a list of objects, it allows the base class to retrieve the list of items without knowing about the concrete class. However, it has to be lazy loaded or it won't work (I need to run some other code before running it), which is why I needed to pass it as a Func so I could store and invoke it later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap the property in an lambda:

```
GetFish(() => getFish);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous lambda:

```
GetFish(() => { return getFish; })
```